# jQuery Data-Filtering

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, filter

Please see the following link:

http://www.momentapps.co.uk/root

We currently have a list of thumb-nail images that are scrollable, these link to to specific pages. Now on the left we have 4 drop-downs. Inside these drop-downs we have some filters set up, so opening location and selecting US would filter out US companies keeping only US companies. Moving down to "Capability" allows to further filter and for example selecting systems would show all companies who do systems in the US.

At current choosing US brings up US and then selecting systems brings up all systems and not systems specifically from the US.. I'm looking to filter results and then filter results again based on the first selection. This is currently all done in Data-filters but I'm not sure that is gonna cut it.. my jQuery is not the best!

CODE:

```
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-1" tabindex="1">
        <span>Location</span>
        <ul class="portfoliofilter" tabindex="1">
            <li class="filter" data-filter="us"><a id="hide" href="#">US</a></li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter="uk"><a id="hide1" href="#">UK</a></li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter="thailand"><a id="hide" href="#">Thailand</a></li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter="mexico"><a id="hide" href="#">Mexico</a></li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter="malaysia"><a id="hide" href="#">Malaysia</a></li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter="france"><a id="hide" href="#">France</a></li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter="holland"><a id="hide" href="#">The Netherlands</a></li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter="all"><a clase="show_all" id="hide" href="#"> Locations</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

The above is for the drop-downs and the following in was it targets

```
<div class="filter_list">
    <ul class="portfolio">

        <li class="item us sub prec engines frame">
            <div class="portfolioitem">
            <a name="click" class="active" href="index.html"><img src="_includes/img/thumbs/absolute.jpg"></a>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="item us lra sub com prec frame">
            <div class="portfolioitem">
                <a name="click" class="low" href="_pages/amt.html"><img src="_includes/img/thumbs/amt.jpg"></a>

            </div>
        </li>
```

etc etc

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your jQuery? It would be helpful if you posted a http://jsfiddle.net also.

Comment: I'm using the mix-it up plugin.. https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/ if that helps .. thanks

Comment: Not much. Posting your code will make it easier for people to help you - at the moment you're asking people to wade through a bunch of unrelated code on your website to work out what you're doing. If you can reduce the problem to a simple demo on jsfiddle it will make it even easier for people to help you (and therefore you're more likely to get an answer).